# Html.CheckBox Specify Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do we specify the class of Html.CheckBox ?

I am trying something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
   @Html.CheckBox("chk_", abc.IsChecked, new { @class="checkbox" })
```

THanks !!

Comment: This should work just fine! what is the output you are getting from this?

Comment: This is what i am getting as an error: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<BCVA.Models.ABC>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, bool, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that IsChecked is not a bool!

Comment: @Html.CheckBox("chk_", abc.IsChecked) : This works fine, but when i add the new class attribute, it fails.

Comment: forgot to mention .. if you open the errors window it will tell you which one of your input is incorrect (e.g. could not cast type X to Y)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When specifying class, compiler puts a check to confirm that the bool value is not nullable, i fixed the datatype from null-able bool to bool, and it ran fine.

@Html.CheckBox("chk_", abc.IsChecked, new { @class="checkbox" })