# How to force checkbox to behave like radiobutton, double loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have checkboxes in 2 for loops. I want to force them to behave like radiobuttons. There should be only one option chosen for each Q (first loop).
I have a peace of code, but it doesn't work. How to change it?

```
script type="text/javascript">  

    var classes = $('.myDiv').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('class');
    }).get();

    $.each(classes, function(i) {
        $(classes[i]).change(function() {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $(classes[i]).prop('checked',false);
            if(checked[i]) {
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The short answer is: use radio buttons. Don't try to make an element behave like another element - just use the one that provides the closest thing to the behaviour you need. Even if you can make checkboxes behave like this (and you can), your users will be confused, as they will expect the behaviour of a checkbox and get something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a common class to the checkbox input and then use that class like below

```js
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
      $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't change it to make it work in my case. I have problems to get class names, because they're changing in time. Do you have any tips how to make it in my code?

Comment: can you add a common class to all the checkbox input apart from the unique class names you get

Comment: @Html.CheckBox("chk_", abc.IsChecked, new { @class="checkbox" })

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958434/html-checkbox-specify-class

Comment: My class has a different name for every question. In my case it is @class=@Model.Question[i].Id. How to get this class name? I can't just write class="something". That is my problem.

Comment: The problem is that now I can check only one checkbox but for ALL questions, I want to be able to check one checkbox for one question

Comment: you can add a class to tr and from there you can target it :)

Comment: I have no idea how to make it work. Because I would have different class for every question. But i don;t know the number of classes and of course names, because name would be @class="@Model.Id"

Comment: i changed the code further more, check it out @karo96 made sure it is going to stick to the same row :)

Comment: Like that?   <tr class=@Model.Question[i].Id>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Question[i].Answer[j].IsChecked, new { type = "checkbox" })</tr>?
And how to change jquery now? to separe buttons for every question?

Comment: There's always sth wrong when I try it :( I can't subtract my table the way it could work :(

Comment: I edited my code for a table. Now every question should be in other <tr><td>. But i still can change inly one button for all questions. What am I doing wrong?